# I want to get key value pair as response from mysql xdev api response

Tags: mysql, node.js

// Working with Relational Tables

```
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
var myTable;
```

// Connect to server using a connection URL`enter code here`

```
mysqlx
    .getSession({
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 33060
    })
    .then(function (session) {
        // Accessing an existing table
        myTable = session.getSchema('testdb').getTable('test-table');

        // Insert SQL Table data
        return myTable
            .insert(['name', 'birthday', 'age'])
            .values(['Laurie', '2000-5-27', 19])
            .execute()
    })
    .then(function () {
        // Find a row in the SQL Table
        return myTable
            .select()

            .execute();
    })
    .then(function (myResult) {
        console.log(myResult.fetchAll());
    });
```

I am getting response like this:

```
[
  [ 'Laurie', '2000-5-27', 19 ],
  [ 'Laurie', '2000-5-27', 19 ],
  [ 'Laurie', '2000-5-27', 19 ]
]
```

But I want to get responses like this:

```
[{'name':'Laurie', 'birhday':'2000-5-27','age':19},
{'name':'Laurie', 'birhday':'2000-5-27','age':19},
{'name':'Laurie', 'birhday':'2000-5-27','age':19}

]
```

How to acihieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a regular table, you need to do that manually using the [`getColumns()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-RowResult.html#getColumns__anchor) method.

Something like the following:

```
const columns = myResult.getColumns();
const rows = myResult.fetchAll(); 
console.log(rows.map(row => row.reduce((res, value, i) => ({ ...res, [columns[i].getColumnLabel()]: value }), {})));
```

With a Document Store collection, the atomic unit is a document which is already represented as a JSON value in the database and maps to a plain JavaScript object in the client, so there is no need for that.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js